# Transit tourism questions - should they ask the minimum time to exit the airport?

Tags: discussion

There are a lot of questions on transit tourism, i.e. in the form [Anything to do for a 4h35 stopover in Guangzhou?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44892/anything-tod-o-for-a-4h35-stopover-in-guangzhuo). While often the transit time mentioned in a question is at least 6-8 hours, recently we have seen some questions about relatively short durations in pretty large airports.

Both kind of questions (with short or long layovers) are perfectly answerable, but I am worried because answers do not necessarily explain the minimum time one needs to exit the airport and come back. So, when we will have multiple times the question about the same airport for multiple durations, while some with particularly long or particularly short durations will obviously be marked as duplicates, what about those with the duration being in the "risk" zone?

One way would be to edit the questions to ask for what range of duration would be enough to go out and visit, or what range of duration it would take to exit the airport and come back. With this, it is up to the reader to decide whether it is worth exiting, not up to the answerer.

Comment: I saw a question from a fellow planning a layover in Iceland. The interval was too long to sit in the airport; but too short to do anything meaningful in Iceland. Reykjavik isn't all that exotic and that was the only real option.

Answer (score 5):

Answers covering the main scenarios (i.e. instead of simply “yes, one hour is enough”, providing an estimate of the minimum/comfortable time for transfer/for a sight-seeing tour) are definitely better. Inviting people to edit questions in this direction or even doing it for them sounds like a good idea.